# Huge lots of errors when importing libraries

Tags: python, import

I suddenly got a lot of errors when importing libraries that i didn't have in the same script (exactly the same script) a few hours ago.
This is what I import:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.core.common.is_list_like = pd.api.types.is_list_like
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import datetime
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf
import plotly
from plotly import figure_factory as ff
import os
```

And this is the huge amount of errors:

```
sh: module: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
sh: error importing function definition for `module'
sh: switchml: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
sh: error importing function definition for `switchml'
sh: scl: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
sh: error importing function definition for `scl'
```

As I said, I didn't get any of those errors earlier, and can't find anything to fix it over the internet.

I'm using the last version of atom editor on fedora28.

Thanks for reading, guys! :)

Comment: How are you running this script? I don't see how you're getting multiple failing errors

Comment: Those aren't Python error messages.

Comment: I run it with the library 'script' in the atom editor.

Comment: See [Unexpected end of file sh: error importing function definition after update to v1.12.1 #165](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-flake8/issues/165#issuecomment-265187130), [getting errors while using terminal #293](https://github.com/platformio/platformio-atom-ide-terminal/issues/293), and possibly [Strange lines in terminal #120](https://github.com/platformio/platformio-atom-ide-terminal/issues/120#issuecomment-274756065).